# How can I receive a webhook on a Git push?

Tags: git, webhooks, dokku

How can I automatically create a Git repository then when a commit is pushed to it send a POST request with a blob to http://example.com/webhook?

The objective of this is to create a online service that works like Dokku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by creating a [Git hook](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks), in particular a [post-receive hook](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_code_post_receive_code).

If you want to wait for http://example.com/webhook to respond to the POST (good luck, with that URL) and only accept the push based on what it says, you’ll need to use a pre-receive hook instead.